# Cannot deploy strapi using mysql to Heroku

Tags: mysql, heroku, strapi

I'm new to Heroku but this seems pretty simple/straightforward.

I have a strapi application that works fine on my local machine.  I've pushed that application to github and then connected it to Heroku in the Staging section. I've added the mysql package to strapi.

I've added config vars for ADMIN_JWT_SECRET, DATABASE_HOST, DATABASE_NAME, DATABASE_PASSWORD, DATABASE_USERNAME, and NODE_ENV into Heroku.

My config/server.js is minimal:

```
module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
  host: env('HOST', '0.0.0.0'),
  port: env.int('PORT', 1337),
  admin: {
    auth: {
      secret: env('ADMIN_JWT_SECRET'),
    },
  },
});
```

my config/database.js is also simple:

```
module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
  defaultConnection: 'default',
  connections: {
    default: {
      connector: 'bookshelf',
      settings: {
        client: 'mysql',
        host: env('DATABASE_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        port: env.int('DATABASE_PORT', 3306),
        database: env('DATABASE_NAME', 'strapi'),
        username: env('DATABASE_USERNAME', 'user'),
        password: env('DATABASE_PASSWORD', 'pass'),
        ssl: env.bool('DATABASE_SSL', false),
      },
      options: {}
    },
  },
});
```

Upon deployment, I cannot access the site.  I get this error:

Application error
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details. You can do this from the Heroku CLI with the command
heroku logs --tail

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,

Andrew

Answer (score 1):

Heroku doesn't support MySql themselves. A few third parties will rent you space on their MySql dynos.

And Heroku supports no database at all running on `localhost`. That would mean it was running on the same web dyno as your application, and that's not how Heroku works.

You can add a postgreSQL service to your Heroku app. They offer a modestly sized free tier of that service, enough to do a proof of concept CMS deployment.

strapi offers a guide to Heroku deployment. https://strapi.io/documentation/developer-docs/latest/deployment/heroku.html